# How to Override MUI CSS in a React Custom Component which uses MUI Component in it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Below is the Custome Component which i created in Reactjs and used in different component  :

```
function SearchBox({ handle, placeholder, inputType, ...props}) {
  return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'flex-end',
                margin: 1,
                marginTop: 0,
                maxHeight: '30px'
            }}
        >
            <TextField
                sx={{
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    width: '100%'
                }}
                variant={inputType || 'standard'}
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position='start'>
                            <SearchIcon
                                sx={{
                                    color: 'action.active',
                                    mb: 0.2,
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    alignItems: 'flex-end'
                                }}
                            />
                        </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    placeholder: placeholder || 'Search'
                }}
                onChange={handle}
            />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

I am using this Component in Some Other Component `<SearchBox handle={Keyword}/>`
so how to override css for TexField and Box of the SearchBox component? i don't want to touch the SearchBox need to override css properties from the place where i am using this component.

When i did Inspect on the Browser i saw something like this `<div class="MuiBox-root css-1uqe0j">...</div>`

what is **css-luqe0j**  ?

Can Anyone Help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the `SearchBox` component ***at all***, you have [a](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/) [few](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#nesting-the-theme) [options](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#deeper-elements-3), the most reasonable of which (IMO) is to just wrap the `SearchBox` component in a `styled` component that then targets elements contained within the `SearchBox` (it's child), for example:

```
const SearchBoxStyleOverrides = styled("div")({
  ".MuiBox-root": {
    padding: "2rem",
    backgroundColor: "green"
  },
  ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
    color: "red"
  },
  ".MuiInput-input": {
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }
});

export default function YourApp() {
  return (
    <SearchBoxStyleOverrides>
      <SearchBox />
    </SearchBoxStyleOverrides>
  );
}
```

Which produces: *(ugliness is for effect)*
[image: sorry for making this ugly]

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-dubinsky-wjthtt?file=/demo.js

And to answer your secondary question ("what is `css-luqe0j` ?"), that is the generated css class name for the component -- you don't want to target an element using those because they will frequently change.

Comment: thats great i am able to override the css but when i try to type anything its not working . const SearchBoxStyleOverrides = styled("div")({ 
  '.MuiTextField-root':{
   borderTop: '1.5px solid #ccc',
   borderRight: '1.5px solid #ccc ',
   borderLeft: '1.5px solid #ccc ',
   margin: 'auto',
   }
 });

Comment: @RadhaKalal I'm *pretty certain* that's not an issue with the styled component wrapper we created -- I forked my example and pasted in your changes and it seems to work just fine (https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-violet-3mzsmy?file=/demo.js). Can you reproduce the error in a code sandbox?